# why Webapp2 redirect to a page but it's not reload?

Tags: webapp2

I am using a webapp2 in GAE, when I called self.redirect to some page like below:

```
self.redirect(some_url)
```

which returned a page looks like cached, I have to refresh/reload the page so that I would get latest data.

Is there any cache setting for webapp2? or I have to set some properties for response of that page? Please advise.

Comment: try adding a dummy query string to the url to make sure you load a new version of your page.

Comment: @voscausa i tried, but failed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my project I've fixed that by adding `time.sleep(0.1)` just before the `self.redirect('someurl')`  call.

Not sure if it is a best way to solve the problem, but pages started to show most recent info.

---

### Edit: beware of consistency issue

Check out [@Lindsay](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16879275/why-webapp2-redirect-to-a-page-but-its-not-reload/21721681#23188229) answer. Using `time.sleep(0.1)` might give you the expected result in a local environment, but you **cannot** trust it in a production environment. If you really need results to be strongly consistent, use an ancestor query, not `time.sleep(0.1)`.

Comment: There is also a notion that it is better to use ancestor queries in production - https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/datastore/queries#ancestor_queries

Answer (score 5):

My guess is that this is happening because the earlier page is updating an entity that is then being accessed on the later page by means of a non-ancestor query. A non-ancestor query provides eventual-consistency rather than strong-consistency, so the problem is not that the page isn't being refreshed, but that it's showing what the data looked like before the update was completed. When you refresh, or add a call to time.sleep(), you may be providing enough time for the datastore to catch up, especially during testing. However, in production, your sleep may not be long enough in all cases, and the same is true of a page-refresh.

If you check your application and find out that you are using a non-ancestor query, and therefore your problem is indeed eventual-consistency vs strong-consistency, a Google search will show you that many pages discuss that topic; here's one: https://cloud.google.com/developers/articles/balancing-strong-and-eventual-consistency-with-google-cloud-datastore#ftnt_ref1.

The simplest solution seems to be to create an entity group and use an ancestor query, though that comes with a possible performance hit and a limitation of one update per second per entity group.

Comment: This should be the selected answer, thanks for pointing out the consistency issue @Lindsay. I changed to an ancestor query and it worked. Using `time.sleep(0.1)` is misleading because it might not work in a production environment. There's no way to know what time interval to use in the sleep because propagation in Datastore might vary.

Answer (score 1):

Got the same problem I have done a trick which is not good but helped me anyway. Called a temporary view file then did html redirect:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0.5;URL='/'">
```

Hope it helps. any one with a better answer?

Answer (score 0):

Do you call `return` immediately after the `self.redirect(some_url)`?  It may be falling through to other code that renders a page.